# Find the equation of tangent at origin to the curve $y^2=x^2(1+x+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

How do I find the equation of tangent at $(0,0)$ to the curve $y^2=x^2(1+x+x^2)$ ?
Differentiating and putting the value of $x$ and $y$ gives an indeterminate form.

Can we trace the curve and geometrically make tangents and find their equation ?

Comment: Indeterminate or complex

Comment: Sorry, the question is wrong I need to edit it.

*Edited

Comment: Do you know implicit differentiation

Comment: As it is an algebraic curve,  the equation of the tangents at $(0,0)$ are given by the homogeneous part of  lowest degree, i.e. $x=0$.

Comment: Oh god I am really really sorry, the question is still wrong :| I will update that. *Edited changed $x$ to $x^2$

Comment: Hopefully thus time its right:)

Comment: How can a vertical line like $\;x=0\;$ be "the tangent"?

Comment: The answer given is $y=x$ and  $y=-x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^2=x^2(1+x+x^2)\implies 2yy'=2x(1+x+x^2)+x^2(1+2x)=4x^3+3x^2+2x\implies$$

$$y'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4x^3+3x^2+2x}{2y}=\pm\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4x^2+3x+2}{2\sqrt{1+x+x^2}}=\pm1$$

and thus the tangent doesn't exist since $\;y=|x|\sqrt{1+x+x^2}\;$ and $\;\frac x{|x|}=\pm1\;$

Comment: This looks correct but I have been provided with the answer $ y=x $ and $y=−x$

Comment: @DhirajBarnwal I think this curve has a singular point at the origin. You first said $\;x=0\;$ , and then you added that it is $\;y=-x\;,\;\;y=x\;$ . How "the tangent" can be either a vertical line or two different lines? Perhaps I don't know some definition you're using.

Comment: I guess the question is wrong then. The hint provided says that since the curve is passing through the origin, comparing the terms of lowest degree we get $y^2=x^2$

Comment: @DhirajBarnwal Exactly , and then the curve crosses the origin through to different paths and that makes it, in my opinion, not differentiable there, so there is no tangent.

Comment: @Joanpemo You are assuming it as a function. But it is a curve. it can have multiple tangents at a point!

Comment: Thank you @Tim , but I really can't see how that's possible. If it were a two variables function then I understand it can have direction derivatives or a tangent plane, yet the question seems to imply that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2=x^2+x^3+x^4$$

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+3x^2+4x^3$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x+3x^2+4x^3}{2y}$$

Now, equation of tangent line at (0,0) is (eqn 1):

$$y=\frac{dy}{dx}\big{|}_{(0,0)}(x)$$

Since $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ yields 0/0 form, we use limits to evaluate the tangent:

$$\lim_{x,y\to0} \frac{2x+3x^2+4x^3}{2y} $$
$$ \equiv\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2x+3x^2+4x^3}{2|x|\sqrt{1+x+x^2}} $$

Here we find:

- $\lim_{x\to0^-} \dfrac{2x+3x^2+4x^3}{2|x|\sqrt{1+x+x^2}}=-1 $ and
- $\lim_{x\to0^+} \dfrac{2x+3x^2+4x^3}{2|x|\sqrt{1+x+x^2}}=+1 $

The limit is known to not exist, as LHL and RHL don't agree. but in my opinion it doesn't matter if this limit of slope function $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ exists or not, since its a curve.

so from eqn 1

$$\implies y = \pm x$$

Comment: A limit in the real numbers system cannot yield two different numbers as, if it exists, it is unique.

Comment: This is not a function! Its a curve! It can have two limits!

Comment: What you wrote three lines before the end is a limit of one variable: it can't have two different values, in my opinion...not even if it is a function of several variable it can have several values.

Comment: I dont know how to understand this, but actually the LHL and RHL are different and so limit of the slope function doesn't exist. But we don't care if the limit of the function the slope function ($\frac{dy}{dx}$) exists or not. It yields two values, which are both sensible.